# How to fixed navbar on bottom in mobile and top in web browse?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navigation, bottomnavigationview

Is any way to display navigation bar on top when it's open in web browser and bottom when it's open in mobile?

Comment: Yup using `@media`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media` to have CSS for different screen sizes

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 656px) {
  div {
    top:auto;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```